# Categorize Results in HTML/PHP Table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `dishes` and `days_avail`, where `dishes` contains information regarding dishes cooked and `days_avail` contains what days a certain dish is available.

`days_avail` looks like this:

```
daysid || dishid || monday || tuesday || wednesday || friday
```

daysid: unique id

dishid: dish id from dishes table

Mon - Fri: boolean

So, what I am able to do is pull the dishes and show relevant info along with what day it is available on. However, what I am trying to accomplish is categorizing the dishes by the days they are available. So something like this:

```
Monday
dish name
dish desc desc desc

Tuesday
Dish name
dish desc dish desc
```

My query is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dishes JOIN days_avail ON days_avail.dishid = dishes.id WHERE user_id = :cookid ORDER BY days_avail.daysid";
  try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':cookid' => $cookid
  ));
}
    catch(Exception $error) {
  echo '<p class="bg-danger">', $error->getMessage(), '</p>';
}

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
      $dish_name = $row['dish_name'];
      $dish_desc = $row['dish_desc'];
      $dish_price = $row['dish_price'];
      $mon = $row['Monday'];
      $tues = $row['Tuesday'];
      $wed = $row['Wednesday'];
      $thurs = $row['Thursday'];
      $fri = $row['Friday'];
    }
```

I can't group the dishes under one day its available. I have tried using a if statement (example: if($mon == 1) { echo "Monday // dish_info, etc" }) but this results in the heading being repeated for each dish.

I have also tried using java handlebars to more or less run a query and then simply "stuff" the results in the (appropriate) div boxes but did not work.

I am get a complete lost here. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you try using a `group by` in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by putting your returned rows into an array, based off the day available-

```
...your query code...

$days=array('Monday'=>array(),'Tuesday'=>array(),'Wednesday'=>array(),'Thursday'=>array(),'Friday'=>array());

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    foreach($days as $day=>$array){
        if($row[$day]){
            $days[$day][]=array('dish_name'=>$row['dish_name'],
                                'dish_desc'=>$row['dish_desc'],
                                'dish_price'=>$row['dish_price']);
        }
    }
}
```

now just loop over your `$days` array

```
foreach($days as $day => $dishes){
    echo "<h2>$day</h2>";
    foreach($dishes as $dish){
        echo $dish['dish_name']."<br />";
        echo $dish['dish_desc']."<br />";
        echo $dish['dish_price']."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, perfectly understood the concept. Working very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dishes JOIN days_avail ON days_avail.dishid = dishes.id WHERE user_id = :cookid ORDER BY days_avail.daysid";
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':cookid' => $cookid
    ));
}
catch(Exception $error) {
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">', $error->getMessage(), '</p>';
}

$dishes = array(
    'mon'   = array(),
    'tues'  = array(),
    'wed'   = array(),
    'thurs' = array(),
    'fri'   = array()
);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    $dish = array(
        'name'  => $row['dish_name'],
        'desc'  => $row['dish_desc'],
        'price' => $row['dish_price']
    );

    $mon   = (bool) $row['Monday'];
    $tues  = (bool) $row['Tuesday'];
    $wed   = (bool) $row['Wednesday'];
    $thurs = (bool) $row['Thursday'];
    $fri   = (bool) $row['Friday'];

    if ($mon) {
        $dishes['mon'][] = $dish;
    }

    if ($tues) {
        $dishes['tues'][] = $dish;
    }

    if ($wed) {
        $dishes['wed'][] = $dish;
    }

    if ($thurs) {
        $dishes['thurs'][] = $dish;
    }

    if ($fri) {
        $dishes['fri'][] = $dish;
    }
}

// iterate over Monday dishes
foreach ($dishes['mon'] as $dish) {
    // $dish['name'], $dish['desc'], $dish['price']
}

// and so on....
```